# XMLHttpRequest returns zero in popup extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Trying to download a page in a **popup** code but it returns status of zero.

```
console.log("Req");
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open(
    "GET",
    "http://www.google.com",
    true);
req.onload = function() {
  console.log("DONE!!!");
  console.log(req.responseText);
}
req.send(null);
```

I did set this in my manifest:

```
"permissions": [
   "http://www.google.com"
]
```

Whats wrong? Why the response is **zero**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google.com is not the best page for testing. I bet when you open it in a browser it redirects you to your localized google page (it redirects me to `http://www.google.ca` for example). So you would need to add that redirected url to the permissions as well.

Another problem is that your permission domain does not end with `/`:

```
"permissions": [
   "http://www.google.com/",  "http://www.google.ca/"
]
```